# Remove points from a plot without removing the lines

Tags: r, plot

is there someone who knows how to remove the points without removing the line in a plot?

I have created a plot like the last one in the link bellow with a binomial scale.

Yes the points are informative but when adding more lines in the plot and concentrating on the different trends for the different lines the points feels a bit needless. And second just being curious how to alter the appearance in a plot.

[image: binomial scale]

The commandos i have used is:

```
> plot(Leaves>0~light,x,xlab="Light",ylab="Response")

> g=glm(formula = Leaves > 0 ~Light, family = binomial ,data =V.riviniana, na.action = na.exclude)

> curve(predict(g,data.frame("Light"=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE,lty=8)

> g2=glm(formula=Leaves>0~Light, family=binomial, data=V.biflora,na.action=na.exclude)

> curve(predict(g2,data.frame(Light"=x), type="resp"),add=TRUE,lty= 1)
```

Comment: First, why?  The points are very informative, and you'll lose a lot of information if you remove them.  Second, it depends on how you created the picture.  To help us answer you better, please post reproducible code.

Comment: I think it is possible is set the size, transparency of the points. You can tweak those settings to effectively remove the points.

Comment: Syntax issue in the last line. And I agree with @Aaron.  The points are very important in this display.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `type="n"` parameter to `plot`

```
plot(Leaves>0~light, x, xlab="Light", ylab="Response", type="n")
```

and it will not display the points.